# Any potential pitfall of using inline static data member?

Tags: c++, inline, c++17, static-members, inline-variable

C++17 introduced [inline variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline), and an inline static data member can be defined in the class definition with an initializer. It does not need an out-of-class definition. For example,

```
struct X {
  inline static int n = 1;
};
```

Given this, I see no reason not to *always use* inline static data members, for the neat syntax. Any pitfall of doing this? Note that I don't mind slower compilation.

Comment: If your code can require C++17 (or later), then I'd use it.

Comment: @JiveDadson Only `constexpr` static data member is implicitly inline.

Comment: I recommend reading up on what those keywords mean as applied to variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a pitfall, but here's one reason not to use an `inline`: if the initial value of the variable is not just a trivial constant, but something more complicated:

```
struct X {
  inline static int n = and_then_more(figure_out_where_n_comes_from());
};
```

Now, the declaration of `figure_out_where_n_comes_from()` and `and_then_more()` must be pulled into the header file, now.

Also, whatever `figure_out_where_n_comes_from()` returns must also be declared. It could be some horribly overcomplicated `class`, which then gets passed to `and_then_more()`, as a parameter, to finally compute the initial value for `n`.

And everything that `#include`s the header file where `X` is declared must now include all the header files for all of these dependencies.

But without an `inline`, all you have is:

```
struct X {

   static int n;
};
```

And you need to deal with all these dependencies only in one translation unit that instantiates `X::x`. Nothing else that `#include`s only `X`'s header file cares about it.

In other words: [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). If it's necessary to reimplement where the initial value of `n` comes from, you get to recompile only one translation unit, instead of your entire source code.

Comment: Note the alternative: `static inline int n = make_n();` -- export a `make_n` instead of a static member variable of a class.  Which is just kicking the can down the road (you still need something defined in one spot, just now it is a function not a variable)